# Prevent table columns from expanding CSS

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I've already declared `table-layout:fixed` but still the column expands when data doesn't fit in the width specified by the code. 
Here is my CSS code:

```
table
{
font-size:15px;
table-layout: fixed;
}

#problem-submission td, #problem-submission th 
{
    font-size:15px;
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    padding:2px 7px 1px 5px;
}
#problem-submission td
{
height:10px;
}

#problem-submission th
{
   font-size:15px;
   height :25px;
   text-align:left;
   padding-top:1px;
   padding-bottom:1px;
   background-color:#E6E6E6;
   color:black;
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the `width`?

Comment: @NickR only in <th> tag. <tr>
  <th width="30%">User</th>
  <th width="30%">Result</th>
  <th width="20%">Time</th>
  <th width="20%">Lang</th>
  </tr>  should i mention in <td> also?

Comment: Have your tried with : text-overflow: ellipsis; or something similar ?

Comment: @Mianm84 didn't tried it .

Comment: then in the td style, add this property, and the text overflow will not grow your width, but will be hidden and replaced with '...'. Notice that you need to specify the ref width of your td. I see now width declaration in your code.

Comment: didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Set Width and/or Height values, then it wont expand.

Divs, span and on, just read the value you give and wont take any higher value, also you can use max-height and max-width on those tags you want to set a limit to the size you desire.

Answer (score 0):

try this on your elements:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd also go with fixed width and height values for the cells. That way youo can be 100% sure that the cells don't change their size.